# It is possible to store a .cs class in a List and call a function

Tags: c#

I want to store many classes in a List. So I can later iterate this List to extract values from those different classes.

I wonder if the below is possible to do. The code below will show exactly what I am trying to do:

```
//This works fine!
Features.testclass tc = new Features.testclass();
String getvalue = tc.getvalue(); //returns the string "Hello"


/*--------------------------------------------------------------------*/
//The code below is wrong but,
//Now I want to store a class in a List somhow and try to call getvalue() somehow. Is this possible?
List<Object> classLIST = new List<Object>();
classLIST.Add(tc);

//How to get the String "Hello" now here?
//String getvalue2 = classLIST[0].getvalue();..... ????
```

Comment: Maybe a `List<Features>` instead? Or, do you mean you want a List of different class types? In this case, do these classes share an Interface?

Comment: I am not sure if `List<Features` will do it. No I only want a list that Holds .cs classes that I have declared exactly as in my example, nothing else. Then I want to be able to use that classes from the list and call a function: `getvalue()`. Exactly as the example shows.

Comment: Use a `List<Features>` then (referring to the class file extension is not that useful).

Comment: Please, do me a favor and learn the terms. In object orientation, there are *classes*. "CS Classes" is not a term. Typically, you store *objects* in a list, not *classes*. It will help yourself if you use the right terms.

Comment: Thomas, I know exactly that. But that is my whole question. Is it possible to store classes or point to them somehow as I try to do in any type of way?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to learn generics. Read this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/

Comment: It would really help if you'd provide a [mcve] - at the moment we don't have examples of the multiple different classes you want, or know whether they've got anything in common. It would also help make your question easier to read and understand if you followed .NET naming conventions.

Comment: In my previous comment, I missed the nested class. You should have a `List<Features.testclass>`.

Comment: why do you keep saying.cs class? A instantiated class is an object. It sounds like you want to store a list of objects. Yes, this is a very common thing.

Comment: As Thomas mentions, you are not storing a class, you're storing an object which is an instance of that type. Correct terminology __is__ important when asking questions here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative to inheriting from a base class, you can have each class implement the same interface, and make the list based on that same interface.  That will allow you to have disparate class types in your list.

```
public interface IFace
{
    string GetValue();
}

public class Fred : IFace
{
    public string GetValue { return "Fred"; }
}

public class Barney : IFace
{
    public string GetValue { return "Barney"; }
}

...

var MyList = new List<IFace>();
MyList.Add(new Fred());
MyList.Add(new Barney());
..
var result = MyList[0].GetValue();
```

Comment: Peter, Thank you very much. This is a perfect solution actually for my case. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

First option is to use a BaseClass which has `getvalue();`  function. Your child classes must inherit from the baseclass. in that case you can have,

```
class BaseClass
{
   public string GetValue() {}
}

class ChildClass1 : BaseClass
{
}

class ChildClass2 : BaseClass
{
}


List<BaseClass> classLIST = new List<BaseClass>();
classList.Add(new ChildClass1())
classList.Add(new ChildClass2())

String getvalue1 = classLIST[0].Getvalue();
String getvalue2 = classLIST[0].Getvalue();
```

In second option, you can stick with what you did

```
String getvalue2 = ((TestClass)classLIST[0]).Getvalue();
```

you can't go wrong with first option, however the second one does not have type checking and it can throw exception.

[Check this .Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/89dw58)

Comment: That was interesting. I must look into this: If I try to write this `String getvalue2 = ((Features)classLIST[0]).Getvalue();` Features is underlined and dont exist? I have a folder in the solution called: Features ? The compiler says: `Feature is a namespace but is used like a type`

Comment: @Andreas It's just a naming conflict. Give your class a bit more specific name.

Comment: I have added an example for you

Comment: From what you've shown, that's _not_ a naming conflict. `Features` is the namespace that the class named `testclass` is in, from your example (side note: give your classes `UpperCased` names). You can cast to a `(Features.testclass)`, but the word `Features` is purely an organizational construct, there is no such _thing_ there to cast to.

Comment: Yes that is true. I am actually now trying the first example with BaseClass as this will work perfecly. But this line `public String GetValue() { }` says `not all code paths return a value`